# Validating GML against XSD schema gives ERROR

Tags: error, xml, gml, validation, xsd

I am a very beginner in GIS and have the following problem I couldn't resolve yet.
I have an XSD schema and an XML document I want to validate against the schema. As expected the XML isn't valid yet, the error saying

> The content of the element
> '{http://www.bafg.de/namespace/dwd/2009}GeneralInformation' is with
> regard to the overarching element
> '{http://www.opengis.net/gml}featureMember' not valid. Expected:
> {http://www.opengis.net/gml}_Feature.

**Here is my XSD schema:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:dwd="http://www.bafg.de/namespace/dwd/2009" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" targetNamespace="http://www.bafg.de/namespace/dwd/2009" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="0.4">
    <import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml" schemaLocation="http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.1.1/base/gml.xsd"/>
    <element name="GeneralInformation" type="dwd:GeneralInformationType" substitutionGroup="gml:_Feature"/>
    <complexType name="GeneralInformationType">
        <complexContent>
            <extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
                <sequence>
                    <element name="ReportType" type="gml:CodeType"/>    
                    <element name="CountryStateCode" type="gml:CodeType"/>
                    <element name="Year" type="gYear"/>
                    <element name="TotalPopulation" type="double"/>
                    <element name="NumberWSZ" type="integer"/>
                    <element name="Groundwater" type="double"/>
                    <element name="Surfacewater" type="double"/>
                    <element name="Inlandwater" type="double"/>
                    <element name="Coastalwater" type="double"/>
                    <element name="Bankfiltrationwater" type="double"/>
                    <element name="ArtificialGrondwaterRecharge" type="double"/>
                    <element name="Rainwater" type="double"/>
                    <element name="Otherwater" type="double"/>
                    <element name="WebsiteAddress" type="anyURI" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    <element name="ResponsibleAuthority" type="string"/>
                    <element name="Name" type="string"/>
                    <element name="Address" type="string"/>
                    <element name="City" type="string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <element name="Telephone" type="string"/>
                    <element name="Fax" type="string"/>
                    <element name="Email" type="string"/>
                    <element name="NoAnnualMonitoringReport" type="boolean"/>
                </sequence>
            </extension>
        </complexContent>
    </complexType>
    <complexType name="GeneralInformationPropertyType">
        <sequence minOccurs="0">
            <element ref="dwd:GeneralInformation"/>
        </sequence>
        <attributeGroup ref="gml:AssociationAttributeGroup"/>
    </complexType>
</schema>
```

And here the XML file showing the error (and I am supposed to modify according to the schema):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gml:FeatureCollection gml:id="Trinkwaser_NRW.xml" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bafg.de/namespace/dwd/2009 Schema.xsd http://www.opengis.net/gml http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.1.1/base/gml.xsd" xmlns:dwd="http://www.bafg.de/namespace/dwd/2009" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <gml:featureMember>
        <dwd:GeneralInformation gml:id="GeneralInformation_1">
            <dwd:ReportType>DWD_1000</dwd:ReportType>
            <dwd:CountryStateCode>Nordrhein-Westfalen</dwd:CountryStateCode>
            <dwd:Year>2013</dwd:Year>
            <dwd:TotalPopulation>3.4</dwd:TotalPopulation>
            <dwd:NumberWSZ>56</dwd:NumberWSZ>
            <dwd:Groundwater>90</dwd:Groundwater>
            <dwd:Surfacewater>5</dwd:Surfacewater>
            <dwd:Inlandwater>5</dwd:Inlandwater>
            <dwd:Coastalwater>0</dwd:Coastalwater>
            <dwd:Bankfiltrationwater>3</dwd:Bankfiltrationwater>
            <dwd:ArtificialGrondwaterRecharge>0</dwd:ArtificialGrondwaterRecharge>
            <dwd:Rainwater>2</dwd:Rainwater>
            <dwd:Otherwater>0</dwd:Otherwater>
            <dwd:WebsiteAddress>http://www.trinkwasser_nrw.de</dwd:WebsiteAddress>
            <dwd:ResponsibleAuthority>Landesgesundheitsamt NRW</dwd:ResponsibleAuthority>
            <dwd:Address>Musterstraße 1</dwd:Address>
            <dwd:City>12345 Musterstadt</dwd:City>
            <dwd:Telephone>123456</dwd:Telephone>
            <dwd:Fax>654321</dwd:Fax>
            <dwd:Email>max.mustermann@musterstadt.de</dwd:Email>
            <dwd:NoAnnualMonitoringReport>true</dwd:NoAnnualMonitoringReport>
        </dwd:GeneralInformation>
    </gml:featureMember>
</gml:FeatureCollection>
```

I don't see the problem, since in the schema the substitutiongroup for "gml:_Feature" is given. What do I need to change?

Comment: What software are you using to do your validation

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which software you are using to do your validation, but for me the only error is you are missing an `<dwd:Name></dwd:Name>` element before the `<dwd:Address>` element.

The following validates using oXygen, I took a copy of your schema called it `Schema.xsd`, and put it on a local server.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gml:FeatureCollection gml:id="Trinkwaser_NRW.xml"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bafg.de/namespace/dwd/2009 http://localhost/xml/schemas/dwd/Schema.xsd http://www.opengis.net/gml http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.1.1/base/gml.xsd"
    xmlns:dwd="http://www.bafg.de/namespace/dwd/2009" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <gml:featureMember>
        <dwd:GeneralInformation gml:id="GeneralInformation_1">
            <dwd:ReportType>DWD_1000</dwd:ReportType>
            <dwd:CountryStateCode>Nordrhein-Westfalen</dwd:CountryStateCode>
            <dwd:Year>2013</dwd:Year>
            <dwd:TotalPopulation>3.4</dwd:TotalPopulation>
            <dwd:NumberWSZ>56</dwd:NumberWSZ>
            <dwd:Groundwater>90</dwd:Groundwater>
            <dwd:Surfacewater>5</dwd:Surfacewater>
            <dwd:Inlandwater>5</dwd:Inlandwater>
            <dwd:Coastalwater>0</dwd:Coastalwater>
            <dwd:Bankfiltrationwater>3</dwd:Bankfiltrationwater>
            <dwd:ArtificialGrondwaterRecharge>0</dwd:ArtificialGrondwaterRecharge>
            <dwd:Rainwater>2</dwd:Rainwater>
            <dwd:Otherwater>0</dwd:Otherwater>
            <dwd:WebsiteAddress>http://www.trinkwasser_nrw.de</dwd:WebsiteAddress>
            <dwd:ResponsibleAuthority>Landesgesundheitsamt NRW</dwd:ResponsibleAuthority>
            <dwd:Name></dwd:Name>
            <dwd:Address>Musterstraße 1</dwd:Address>
            <dwd:City>12345 Musterstadt</dwd:City>
            <dwd:Telephone>123456</dwd:Telephone>
            <dwd:Fax>654321</dwd:Fax>
            <dwd:Email>max.mustermann@musterstadt.de</dwd:Email>
            <dwd:NoAnnualMonitoringReport>true</dwd:NoAnnualMonitoringReport>
        </dwd:GeneralInformation>
    </gml:featureMember>
</gml:FeatureCollection>
```

Comment: Many thanks to @nmtoken !
I found out that the error occurred because of a firewall blocking. So the actual error was the missing name as you suggested. thanks a lot!